# Invalid URL as a Valid URL in C#

Tags: c#

how can i add the invalid url (but its valid as it is internal URL) as a valid URL, i am getting an error when i am passing it to System.Uri();

Here is my Uri Code

```
new System.Uri("mailto:DFO%20ABNS%20Techn/DD-DWA/IND@ADW-NGP", true)
```

Comment: can you give as a bit more detail in what you want to do? Do you want to parse an emai address out of this and send out an email? What is the expected result?

Comment: is thr any solution for my such Mailto URL

Answer (score 2):

According to this http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6068.txt *`/` should be %-encoded in mailto 'address-part'*.  .Net will happily take:

```
new System.Uri("mailto:DFOTechn/DD-DWA/IND@ADW-NGP");
```

But it is all considered as part of the host.

encoding the '/' characters gives:

```
new System.Uri("mailto:DFO%20ABNS%20Techn%2FDD-DWA%2FIND@ADW-NGP")
```

Which .Net correctly parses with ADW-NGP as the host.

Comment: is there any other way in which we can preserve %20 i.e space in given string.

Comment: @Ashwin Z Dont understand this question (in comment) this solution *does* preserve the %20

Comment: Thanks @tolanj for replying, but here you can see output of

Uri.UnescapeDataString("mailto:DFO%20ABNS%20Techn/DD-DWA/IND@ADW-NGP") is


"mailto:DFO ABNS Techn/DD-DWA/IND@ADW-NGP" which is
 much more different than 
"mailto:DFOTechn/DD-DWA/IND@ADW-NGP"

Comment: Yes but you are _specifically_ asking it to un-escape which is what it is doing.  new System.Uri("mailto:DFO ABNS Techn%2FDD-DWA%2FIND@ADW-NGP").UserInfo for example is DFO%20ABNS%20Techn%2FDD-DWA%2FIND.

Comment: actually my excel mailto contains same %20 format, so can i add %20 back to my excel using 

worksheetPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new System.Uri("mailto:FSO%20FSAM%20Technology/EY-APP/US@EY-NAmerica"), true); or something like this

Comment: worksheetPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new System.Uri("mailto:DFO%20ABNS%20Techn%2FDD-DWA%2FIND@ADW-NGP"), true) <-- this.

Comment: mailto:DFO%20ABNS%20Techn%2FDD-DWA%2FIND@ADW-NGP

i have included about mailto as a input , but not getting the exact output, the output i got is mailto:DFO%20ABNS%20Techn%2FDD-DWA%2FIND@ADW-NGP but the expected output is mailto:DFO%20ABNS%20Techn/FDD-DWA/FIND@ADW-NGP